# Knex: Create migration with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

I tried the code in the link to create FK:

[how to do knex.js migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624879/how-to-do-knex-js-migrations)

I got an error on line:

```js
table.bigInteger('AddressId')
    .unsigned()
    .index()
    .inTable('Address')
    .references('id');
```

The error:

```
    TypeError: Object # has no method 'inTable' at 
     TableBuilder_MySQL._fn (/Users/lwang/knex/migrations/20150204161920_lei_maigration.js:15:56) at
     TableBuilder_MySQL.TableBuilder.toSQL (/Users/lwang/knex/node_modules/knex/lib/schema/tablebuilder.js:61:12) at 
     SchemaCompiler_MySQL.createTable (/Users/lwang/knex/node_modules/knex/lib/schema/compiler.js:14:53) at 
     SchemaCompiler_MySQL.SchemaCompiler.toSQL (/Users/lwang/knex/node_modules/knex/lib/schema/compiler.js:35:24) at 
     SchemaBuilder_MySQL.SchemaBuilder.toSQL (/Users/lwang/knex/node_modules/knex/lib/schema/builder.js:41:35) at 
     Runner_MySQL. (/Users/lwang/knex/node_modul...
```

Answer (score 39):

This might come a little late but the error is because:

```js
table.bigInteger('AddressId')
    .unsigned()
    .index()
    .inTable('Address')
    .references('id');
```

Should be written:

```js
table.bigInteger('AddressId')
    .unsigned()
    .index()
    .references('id')
    .inTable('Address');
```

The `inTable` function only exists after calling references as explained in the documentation http://knexjs.org/#Schema-inTable

> Sets the "table" where the foreign key column is located after calling
> column.references.

Answer (score 3):

I think there has been a change on how to assign foreign keys.

Instead of doing this:

```
table.bigInteger('AddressId')
.unsigned()
.index()
.inTable('Address')
.references('id');
```

I did this:

```
table.integer('AddressId').unsigned()
tables.foreign('AddressId').references('Address.id');
```

and it worked well for me.

For further reference you can check this github gist: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/245